# Sort associative array by corresponding values in another array from largest to smallest

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have 2 arrays. One is the array to re-arrange and the other has elements that define the desired order of the elements.  I want to sort the first array by the second array values in a descending order.

```
$array = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4];

$array2 = [3, 7, 10, 1];
```

Desired output:

```
 ['c' => 3, 'b' => 2, 'a' => 1, 'd' => 4]
```

Effectively:

- `c => 3` becomes the first element because it relates to `10`.
- `b => 2` becomes the second element because it realtes to `7`.
- `a => 1` becomes the third element because it relates to `3`.
- `d => 4` becomes the fourth element because it relates to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Right, you want to sort with the other array.

```
<?php 

    // your arrays
    $array = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4);
    $array2 = array(3, 7, 10, 1);

    //sort using the other array 
    array_multisort($array2, $array);   

    //reverse it (as asked)
    $result = array_reverse($array, true);
    print_r($result); 

?>
```

Comment: The output of your answer is 
d = lemon
c = apple
b = banana
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php

a = orange

Answer (score 0):

To sort the first `$array` according to the mapped numeric values in `$array2` in descending order, simply:

1. call `array_multisort()`
2. write the array to be assessed in the first parameter
3. write the `SORT_DESC` flag as the second parameter to implement descending sort order then
4. write the array which should be affected as the last parameter.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cr7NE))

```
$array = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4];
$array2 = [3, 7, 10, 1];

array_multisort($array2, SORT_DESC, $array);
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'c' => 3,
  'b' => 2,
  'a' => 1,
  'd' => 4,
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just try with:

```
$array  = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4);
$array2 = array(3, 7, 10, 1);
$output = array();

array_map(function($key, $data) use (&$output){
  $output[$key] = $data;
}, $array2, array_chunk($array, 1, true));
krsort($output);
$output = array_reduce($output, array_merge, array());

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
array (size=4)
  'c' => int 3
  'b' => int 2
  'a' => int 1
  'd' => int 4
```

Comment: This unexplained answer is misunderstanding the requirements.  I've edited the question (after answering) to clarify the task.